# Add data to existing text area in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I add a php variable to a existing textarea by using php or jquery js?

```
Echo”<script> $(document).ready(function(){$(#id).text(‘Test’);});</Script>”;
```

But I get nothing in my text area.

```
<?php include 'dbconn.php';?><?php
echo '<textarea id="id" cols="43" rows="7"></textarea>';
$sqlbetweendate=('SELECT SUM(Pris) FROM bestallning WHERE Datum BETWEEN "'.$dateFrom.'" AND"'.$dateTo.'"');
$result = mysqli_query($read_info,$sqlbetweendate);
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$test = $row['SUM(Pris)']; 
}
Echo” <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#id').text('Test');});</script>”;}?>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Link to jquery is in my footer file. The page loads fully.

Comment: Try giving in value by using echo php variable

Comment: @Raahul and how can I do it? If I cannot add text to textarea. Maybe is it because all code is in php file?

Comment: Can you share your code. I will have a look into it

Comment: This one line of code is full is typos and syntax errors.  Many of them.  Surely you're getting an error in your PHP logs and/or browser console.

Comment: Is there any error message you see when using the code above? What about the rest of that code?

Comment: @David maybe you can help me to correct my syntax errors?

Comment: @Raahul updated

Comment: Do you always write code on a single line? :) Please format your code properly (at least, one statement per line) so we can see it more clearly.

Comment: @AndeasWalz: Start by using normal quotes.  (Word processors are not a good replacement for IDEs.)  Also put quotes around strings.  Aside from that, please provide a complete example of the problem.  Your code currently doesn't contain a textarea element, so there's nothing to put a value in.  If the problem is client-side, focus on that and not on the otherwise unrelated database code.

Comment: @Jeto code is updated

Comment: @AndeasWalz i have added a working code. check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change from this**

```
Echo” <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#id').text('Test');});</script>”;}?>
```

**to this**

```
Echo"<script>document.getElementById('id').value = '$test';</script>";
```

I have tried and works fine. Problem is you are not using defined *$test* anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure **$dateTo** and **$dateFrom** are set, as well as **$read_info**

```
<?php include 'dbconn.php';
$sqlbetweendate=('SELECT SUM(Pris) AS sum_pris FROM bestallning WHERE Datum BETWEEN "'.$dateFrom.'" AND"'.$dateTo.'"');
$result = mysqli_query($read_info,$sqlbetweendate);
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$test = $row['sum_pris']; 
}
?>
<textarea id="id" cols="43" rows="7"><?= $test ?></textarea>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```